# Question on redirection of pages using php

Tags: php, html, database, frontend, backend

Code for page1.php-(Here named as index.php)

```
<?php
require_once "pdo.php";
session_start();
if(!(isset($_SESSION['email'])||isset($_SESSION['password']))
{
$url = "login.html";
}
?>
<html>
<head></head><body>
<?php
if ( isset($_SESSION['error']) ) {
    echo '<p style="color:red">'.$_SESSION['error']."</p>\n";
    unset($_SESSION['error']);
}
if ( isset($_SESSION['success']) ) {
    echo '<p style="color:green">'.$_SESSION['success']."</p>\n";
    unset($_SESSION['success']);
}
if (isset($_SESSION['name']))
echo('<table border="1">'."\n");
$stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT name, email, password, user_id FROM users");
while ( $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
    echo "<tr><td>";
    echo(htmlentities($row['name']));
    echo("</td><td>");
    echo(htmlentities($row['email']));
    echo("</td><td>");
    echo(htmlentities($row['password']));
    echo("</td><td>");
    echo('<a href="edit.php?user_id='.$row['user_id'].'">Edit</a> / ');
    echo('<a href="delete.php?user_id='.$row['user_id'].'">Delete</a>');
    echo("</td></tr>\n");
}
?>
</table>
<!--<a href="add.php">Add New</a>-->
<!--<a href = "login.php">Login</a>-->
```

I have been given page1.php which is the first page when a user opens the application.

In page1.php, a link is given to login. This page redirects to login.php which requires us to login with genuine email and password.

After logging in, it returns to page1.php which has options like add new item to some database or delete/edit data in database and it also has an option of logout which then gives back the original page1.php in which we have been given the option of login.

The problem is if I do operations on database via another page (i.e. like page2.php) it is doable but I am not able to update page1.php after the login.php redirects to page1.php.

How do I work so that login.php page redirects to index.php with modified options? (which are operations on database.) Also how do I do this using href tags in html instead button operations?

Comment: Please visit the [help] to see what and [ask]. HINT: Post effort and CODE.

Comment: I am sorry if the question was long but I had to give a description of the question as it was necessary to be clear about my doubt.Cheers!

Comment: It is not that it is long (true there WAS a lot of unnecessary bla bla). Show some code please

Comment: Oh sure will edit the question.

Comment: Load page1.php in browser1.  Then load page2.php in browser2.  If page2.php changes the database values, page1.php will never know it, since the values showed in page1.pgp were read when the page was built.  Basic HTML-PHP is built that way.  You could fake it using auto-refresh header.  Or use websockets which allow you to push from the server to the browser, but that is another ball game!